# Proving that $x^{2}+2$, $x^{2}-x+4$, and $x^{3}+3x-1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be the polynomials given by:
>   $$f(x)=x^{2}+2$$
>   $$g(x)=x^{2}-x+4$$
>   $$h(x)=x^{3}+3x-1$$
>   Show that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I do this:

$$x^{2}+2=(\sqrt{2}-i x) (\sqrt{2}+i x)$$
then it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
$$x^{2}-x+4=4+(-1+x)(x)$$
then it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
$$x^{3}+3x-1=-1+x (3+x^2)$$
then it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is this true?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I am unable to follow your reasoning for the second and third polynomials. E.g. what does the form $-1+x(3+x^2)$ tell us about being irreducible (equivalently, for degrees 2 and 3, not having a zero)? Also should $t$ be $x$?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles for your questions in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We shall employ [this criterion by Eisenstein.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)
This criterion applies immediately to $f(x)$ with $p=2$. Also, in writing $g(x+3)=x^2+5x+10$, we could apply the criterion to $g(x)$ with $p=5$. Finally, writing $h(x+1)=x^3+3x^2+6x+3$, we again apply the criterion to $h(x)$ with $p=3$. This finishes the proof.
P.S. we also notice here that a polynomial $f(x)$ is reducible if and only if $f(x+c)$ is so for every constant $c$. Hence the above reasonings.

Comment: @Clayton Your appreciation is thanked sincerely.

Comment: @awllower       Very good answer thanks a lot I don't knew Eisenstein's criterion

Comment: @user63192 It is my pleasure to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the following alternative method: if $\,p(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]\,$ is reducible, then it must be reducible over any finite prime field field $\,\Bbb F_p\cong \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\,$ . So take

$$(1)\;\;x^2+2\pmod 5 \;\;\text{(hint:}\,\,\Delta:=b^2-4ac=-8=2\pmod 5\,\text{... not a square in }\,\,\Bbb F_5 )$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x^2-x+4=x^2+6x+4\pmod 7\,\,(\Delta=20=6=-1\pmod 7)$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x^3+3x-1=x^3+x+1\pmod 2\ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

Any non-trivial factorization of those polynomials would contain a linear factor, implying a rational root. The rational root test easily shows there are no rational roots.